# How do I read source code of a npm project with flat dependencies of node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Before npm changed its dependency file structure from `nested` to `flat`, I could easily drill down through the dependency tree to read the source code of a project dependencies and the dependencies of dependencies, therefore to have a deep understanding of a project.

However, nowadays there are thousands of dependencies `flatly` laying in the root `node_modules` of a project, making it impossible to understand and navigate through the true dependency structure of a project.

How do you navigate through a project dependency tree these days if you want to have a deep understanding to an opensource project?

Comment: by looking at package.json in each module? that's what I do, but would be interested in a "better way"™

Comment: @JaromandaX package.json can only tell you the direct dependencies of a module, which is not helpful if you want to `go deep` :(

Comment: you have to follow the rabbit down the rabbit hole :p

Comment: @JaromandaX But prior to npm v3, we don't need any rabbit to explore all levels of the rabbit holes!

Comment: Consider having NPM 2 installation on your system for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

With NPM commandline you may use `npm ls` which will output the depedency graph tree.

Yarn commandline has a nice feature for this kind of investigations : `yarn why`

See documentation here : https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/why/

Here is an example output :

```
yarn why doctrine
yarn why v1.7.0
[1/4] Why do we have the module "doctrine"...?
[2/4] Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4] Finding dependency...
[4/4] Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "doctrine@2.1.0"
info Has been hoisted to "doctrine"
info Reasons this module exists
   - Hoisted from "eslint-plugin-react#doctrine"
   - Hoisted from "eslint#doctrine"
   - Hoisted from "@storybook#react#babel-plugin-react-docgen#react-docgen#doctrine"
=> Found "eslint-plugin-import#doctrine@1.5.0"
info This module exists because "eslint-plugin-import" depends on it.
Done in 0.91s.
```

Comment: To my understand `yarn why` is used to get the dependency chain of a deep nested package from bottom to top until the root project. However what I want is to  explore a project dependency tree and their source code from a top to bottom approch.

Comment: @benjamin you are true. Actually CTRL+CLICK in webstorm works quite well. That plus the "Scroll from source" feature may answer your need.

Comment: my webstorm is very unresponsive and nearly unusable when indexing node_modules. Do you experience the same?

Comment: Yes we usually exclude node_modules from indexing. But that does not prevent CTRL+CLICK from working. Maybe it is dependant of the project configuration (es6/babel/etc.).